# How to edit chart data using office.js within Microsoft Word

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins

I'm creating a word add-in using the word javascript api that pulls data from database, allowing users to create tables/text with the data. I would now like to add the functionality to change charts based on the data

I can see information about editing charts in the documentation for excel, however I can't see anything for word.

Is it possible to edit chart data within word?
If so, would someone be able to provide me an example or link to the appropriate location to look?

I've tried doing it in excel and have made progress but can't see anything on the word side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that there are no chart editing APIs in the Word JavaScript yet. It's a good idea, and you can suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

In the meantime, a chart in Word is a  element in the file's OOXML. You could try the following workaround: Your add-in could get the XML using the `Office.Document.getFileAsync`, edit the OOXML, then use the Word [createDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word_release/word.application?view=office-js#createdocument-base64file-) API to create a new document that is just like the original, but with your chart edits.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I'll add the suggestion, and look into the OOXML.
I wondered if it was due to restrictions with charts on the word online version